# Requesting XLSX file through js to authorized asp.net web api

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-web-api

I have ajax calling my web api to get a xlsx file that is generated when it is called. The xlsx file is in a memory stream that I know is correct because I downloaded it straight from the server and had no issue. However when I try to download the file through the browser it says that the file is invalid. I'm using downloadjs to download the data.

## How I return the Stream

```
 public HttpResponseMessage Function_Name() {
        var stream = getStream();

        HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);

        result.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
        result.Content.Headers.ContentType =
            new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
        return result;
    }
```

## How I get the Stream

```
$.ajax({ url: "urlToData", headers: {
                'Authorization': 'Authorization'
            },
         success: function (data) { download(data, "test.xlsx"); } 
});
```

When I run this code I get a file however that file does not read in excel. The file is also 15.3 KB where the functioning file downloaded straight from the server is actually 10.0kb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was feeling desperate and tried this out: http://www.henryalgus.com/reading-binary-files-using-jquery-ajax/

When I used XMLHttpRequest() it worked correctly.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()

xhr.open('GET', 'url', true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Authorization');
xhr.responseType = 'blob';

xhr.onload = function(e) {
    if(this.status == 200) {
        var blob = this.response;
        download(this.response, "test.xlsx")
    }
}

xhr.send();
```